# A counting function in MatLab

Tags: matlab, math

I would like to create a function in three variables N,l,a using the formula:

[image]

where the outer || in the numerator is the function that counts the elements in the set and the inner || is the magnitude of that complex number.

Here is my code:

```
function density = density(N, l, a) 
m = 0; %m is the number (integer) in the numerator

for n = 1:N
    pn = 1;
    for k = 1:n
        pn = pn*abs(1-exp(2*k*pi*1i*a));
    end  
    
    if pn >= l
       m = m+1;        
    end
    
end
density = m/N;
end
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work as I wished （there is an error saying "Not enough input arguments" in line 4.）

There might be other mistakes in the loops. Can anyone help me correct the code so that it corresponds to the function in the picture?

Comment: How did you run the function? You need to pass in the input arguments.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I see. It is a little weird that usually in the command window Matlab would ask me for inputs for a function but this time it displays an error. Do you think my code coincides with the function in the picture?

Comment: you should not define a variable wit the same name as as the function. This overshadows the function... however, in your case it actually works anyway. Could you post the exact error message? (I doubt that the error is in this line 4 `pn = 1;` ;) )

Comment: @max: line #4 is `for n = 1:N` (empty lines count). This is the first time variable `N` is used. This is when MATLAB decides that not enough parameters were passed into the function when called, as that is the ultimate reason that `N` is not defined.

Comment: OP: I think it does. You can remove your inner loop to make it faster: `pn = prod(abs(1-exp(2*pi*(1:n)*1i*a)));`

Comment: And because a truth value is either 0 or 1, you can then do `m = m + (pn >= l)`. This leads to a way to vectorize the whole function, but it’s probably not worth doing that (you’d use more memory, which slows thing down, a loop is sometimes faster).

Comment: @max Thanks, the line 4 is for n = 1:N

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks for your reminder of the product built-in function. That's really helpful

Comment: `nnz(cumprod(abs(1-exp(2*pi*(1:N)*1i*a)))>=l)/N` ?

Comment: how are you calling the function? (remember that you can't just press "run" because your input variables need to have values...)